# Style the content of an object/embed

Tags: html, css, object-tag

I am developing a small web application in which I have an `object` element (that contains an `embed`) that I use to display small documents.

The documents can be PDFs or plain text files (.txt) that I get from a web service in the form of a base64 string. Then, to show the content, I update the `data` and `src` attributes for the `object` and `embed` respectively. The final result would look something like this (simplified):

```css
object {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<object type="text/plain" data="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh">
  <embed type="text/plain" src="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh" />
</object>
```

All the PDFs look ok (the browser loads them using the plugin), but I am facing some trouble with the text files. The content of the .txt is displayed correctly, but the text looks a bit small and I was asked to make it larger.

I tried changing the font size of the `object` and `embed` but the content is not affected by it:

```
object, embed {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

In Chrome, I saw that the content of the object is a #document that displays the content of the base64 .txt in a `pre`. So I tried to style the `pre`, but only the `pre` tags outside the `object` tag take them, not the one inside it:

```
pre {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Is it possible to give styles to the content of an `object`/`embed`? How could it be done?

Comment: The style on the pre won't apply as you may notice your object behave like an iframe. So your style won't reach it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **pseudo-solution** that worked for me in firefox (locally) and not chrome. The idea is to access the content of the object and append to its head a custom CSS. The issue with this solution is that you will face **cross-origin** issue in some browser as the object behave like an iframe that includes an external content.

**NB**: i used the setTimeout to be sure i run the function after the content of the object is loaded

```js
function addCss() {
 $('object').contents().find("head").append($("<style type='text/css'>pre{font-size:32px;}</style>"));
}

setTimeout(function(){addCss()},2000);
```

```css
object {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<object type="text/plain" data="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh">
  <embed type="text/plain" src="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh" />
</object>
```

Maybe your problem will be how to avoid this cross-origin issue since the content will be yours and server from the same site.